# Get a value from register file to analyzer

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, register

I'm trying to access register values from the analyzer in the test bench. Is there a way to access them without calling the register file module? (I don't want to call the rf module because accessing it writes values in address3 and I don't want to change its value.)

- The analyzer is part of the test bench that compares the result with the expected value, and returns PASS or FAIL. but I need to access the register value so that I can calculate the expected result.

```
module testBench ();

  reg [31:0] instructions [0:10];
  integer i; 
  reg clk;
  reg [31:0] current_instruction; // To hold the current instruction
  wire [31:0] result; // To capture the result from mp_top
   
  mp_top uut (clk, current_instruction, result);

  initial clk = 0; 
  always #5 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial begin
    instructions[0] = 32'b000100_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[1] = 32'b001110_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[2] = 32'b001000_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[3] = 32'b001011_00011_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[4] = 32'b001010_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;     
    instructions[5] = 32'b000001_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[6] = 32'b001101_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[7] = 32'b000110_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[8] = 32'b001001_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[9] = 32'b000101_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[10]= 32'b000111_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i = i + 1) begin
      current_instruction = instructions[i];   
      // here i want to access the values in the register file to analyze it.
      #20;
    end 

    $finish; 
  end
endmodule
```

and here is the register file

```
module reg_file (clk, addr1, addr2, addr3, in , out1, out2);

input clk;
input [4:0] addr1, addr2, addr3;
input [31:0] in;
output reg [31:0] out1, out2;
reg enable = 0; //flag for ensuring there is no garbage values.  

function [31:0] get_register_value;
    input [4:0] register_number; // 5 bits to address 32 registers
    begin
      get_register_value = registers[register_number];
    end
endfunction 
    
// Declare a register array with 32 registers, each 32 bits wide
  reg [31:0] registers [0:31];

    initial begin
    registers[0]  = 32'h0000;
    registers[1]  = 32'h175A;
    registers[2]  = 32'h2FC2;
    registers[3]  = 32'h01E2;
    registers[4]  = 32'h37A6;
    registers[5]  = 32'h1404;
    registers[6]  = 32'h0738;
    registers[7]  = 32'h1494;
    registers[8]  = 32'h3F3A;
    registers[9]  = 32'h129E;
    registers[10] = 32'h10CA;
    registers[11] = 32'h0262;
    registers[12] = 32'h05E6;
    registers[13] = 32'h2642;
    registers[14] = 32'h1D20;
    registers[15] = 32'h15B4;
    registers[16] = 32'h2454;
    registers[17] = 32'h3012;
    registers[18] = 32'h31F6;
    registers[19] = 32'h28F6;
    registers[20] = 32'h2D34;
    registers[21] = 32'h1A7A;
    registers[22] = 32'h20EE;
    registers[23] = 32'h1644;
    registers[24] = 32'h3466;
    registers[25] = 32'h2BE0;
    registers[26] = 32'h07C6;
    registers[27] = 32'h039A;
    registers[28] = 32'h1784;
    registers[29] = 32'h3D80;
    registers[30] = 37'h1600;
    registers[31] = 32'h0000;
  end 
  
  always @(posedge clk) begin 
    if(enable)
    registers[addr3] <= in; // Write 'in' to the register at 'addr3'
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin 
    enable = 1; 
    $display("Instructionx : %h", registers[addr3]);
    out1 = registers[addr1]; // Read from the register at 'addr1'
    out2 = registers[addr2]; // Read from the register at 'addr2'
  end

endmodule
```

```
module alu (
  input [5:0] opcode,
  input [31:0] a, b,
  output reg [31:0] result
);
  // Define opcodes for different operations
  localparam [5:0] ADD   = 6'b000100,
                   SUB   = 6'b001110,
                   ABS   = 6'b001000,
                   NEG   = 6'b001011,
                   MAX   = 6'b001010,
                   MIN   = 6'b000001,
                   AVG   = 6'b001101,
                   NOT   = 6'b000110,
                   OR    = 6'b001001,
                   AND   = 6'b000101,
                   XOR   = 6'b000111;
  
  always @(*) begin
    case (opcode)
      ADD: result = a + b; // Addition
      SUB: result = a - b; // Subtraction
      AND: result = a & b; // Bitwise AND
      ABS: result = (a>0)? a:-a;
      NEG: result = -a;    // negate a  
      MAX: result = (a>b) ? a:b;
      MIN: result = (a<b) ? a:b;
      AVG: result = (a+b)/2; 
      NOT: result = ~a;    // Bitwise NOT (unary operation, ignores b)  
      OR : result = a | b; // Bitwise OR
      XOR: result = a ^ b; // Bitwise XOR   
      
      default: result = 32'b0; // Default case to handle undefined opcodes
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

````
module mp_top (clk, instruction , result );
input clk;
input [31:0] instruction;
output reg [31:0] result;


 // Decode the instruction
  wire [5:0] opcode;
  wire [4:0] address1;
  wire [4:0] address2;
  wire [4:0] address3; 
  wire [31:0] out1;
  wire [31:0] out2;

  // Assign the instruction fields
  assign opcode = instruction[31:26];
  assign address1 = instruction[25:21];
  assign address2 = instruction[20:16];
  assign address3 = instruction[15:11];
  
reg_file file_regester(
.clk(clk),
.addr1(address1),
.addr2(address2),
.addr3(address3),
.out1(out1),
.out2(out2),
.in(result)
); 

alu ALU ( 
.opcode(opcode),
.a(out1),
.b(out2),
.result(result)
);
endmodule



```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code like this into the testbench module.  It uses a Verilog hierarchical specifier to access a signal in a sub-module:

```
#20 $display("uut registers[6]='h%04x", uut.file_regester.registers[6]);
```

Here is the modified testbench code as an example:

```
module testBench ();
  reg [31:0] instructions [0:10];
  integer i; 
  reg clk;
  reg [31:0] current_instruction; // To hold the current instruction
  wire [31:0] result; // To capture the result from mp_top
   
  mp_top uut (clk, current_instruction, result);

  initial clk = 0; 
  always #5 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial begin
    instructions[0] = 32'b000100_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[1] = 32'b001110_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[2] = 32'b001000_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[3] = 32'b001011_00011_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[4] = 32'b001010_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;     
    instructions[5] = 32'b000001_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[6] = 32'b001101_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[7] = 32'b000110_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[8] = 32'b001001_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[9] = 32'b000101_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  
    instructions[10]= 32'b000111_00000_00001_00010_00000000000;  

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i = i + 1) begin
      current_instruction = instructions[i];   
      // here i want to access the values in the register file to analyze it.
      #20;
    end 

    #20 $display("uut registers[6]='h%04x", uut.file_regester.registers[6]);

    $finish; 
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the output when you run a simulation:

```
uut registers[6]='h0738
```

A runnable code example is available on [EDA Playground](https://edaplayground.com/x/QmRi).